# how to get all documents and notes from iPhone swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I want to fetch all documents from iOS device (iPhone or iPad) and show list with documents (files) in my table view. but can't do this.
I try getting all files from iPhone. but nothing working for me.
I get URL directory with help this code

```
func getURLPathFromDocuments() -> URL {
    
    let arrayPaths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let docDirectoryPath = arrayPaths[0]
    print(docDirectoryPath)
    return docDirectoryPath
    
}
```

what to do after this?

Comment: Please clarify: You want to display a list of all files in the "Documents" folder?

Comment: Hint: contentsOfDirectory

Comment: @de. yes.  I want to display in my app a list of all files which contains in the "Documents" folder

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do cannot be achieved as Apple restricts all third-party applications from accessing data of other apps or the system because it can cause privacy and security breaches. Files aside, you can access photos and calendar events. This process is called "Sandboxing". You can read up on it [here](https://www.cnet.com/news/what-apples-sandboxing-means-for-developers-and-users/).

Comment: thank you
I using document picker for my app